# MYSQL - Select rows fulfilling many count conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table (let's say table) with 4 columns -

```
Product_ID, Designer, Exclusive, Handloom
```

ID is the primary key and other 3 columns have values 0 or 1.

Eg - `0` in `Designer` means the product is not designer and `1` means it is designer.

I want to write down a query to select 6 rows out of the given 16 rows, having `>=4 Designer`, `>=4 Exclusive` and `>=4 Handloom` products. 6 rows starting from the top, not limited to top 6 rows only (As there can be multiple combinations, so we will start from top)

I am not able to find out a clear solution to this. Below is the data of the Table table:

```
   Code         Designer    Exclusive   Handloom
    A           1           0           1
    B           1           0           0
    C           0           0           1
    D           0           1           0
    E           0           1           0
    F           1           0           1
    G           0           1           0
    H           0           0           0
    I           1           1           1
    J           1           1           1
    K           0           0           1
    L           0           1           0
    M           0           1           0
    N           1           1           0
    O           0           1           1
    P           1           1           0
```

If I solve it manually, the result would be rows with `Product_ID: a,f,i,j,n,o`

Comment: @amit if you do not know how to format a question then do not update it when its being updated by someone, I am doing it for the last time.

Comment: How does `a` have `>=4 Designer`, `>=4 Exclusive` and `>=4 Handloom` ?  I can't figure out how you came to your solution of `a,f,i,j,n,p`

Comment: Sorry Abhik. This was my first post.

Comment: a doesn't have >=4 Designer. But out of the 6 Products selected, >=4 are designers(A, F, I, J, N, P), >=4 are Exclusive(I, J, N, P), and >=4 are Handloom(A, F, I, J) and total I have 6 items.

Comment: @ Amit . Your question is not clear .You say "write down a query to select 6 rows out of the given 16 rows" and also said  "not limited to top 6 rows only"

Comment: The trick here, as I understand it, is that only 6 rows can be returned. Find the first 6 rows that satisfy the condition where the sum of each column is greater or equal to 4. It's a good question that's hard to explain and is not easily solved.

Comment: I feel as if a recursive query is the right approach here. Start at 'A' and recursively loop up for the next column until the condition is satisfied. I could do this in Postgres or Teradata, but I am 100% unfamiliar with the oddbal MySQL approach to recursive sql.

Comment: @JNevill You got the problem right. I need to select less than or equal to 6 rows, not neccessary the topmost 6 rows. As in the table, top 6 rows are a,b,c,d,e,f that do not satisfy the conditions. So, we had to move down the table to fulfill the conditions.

Comment: Did you exclude B because it only has a single flag among the three columns?

Comment: @shawnt00 you need the first 6 records you can find that satisfy the three conditions, or perhaps think like.. the lowest 6 letters that satisfy the three conditions. Adding B would cause your last Letter in the list to go past 'P' so it wouldn't be the overall lowest set.

Comment: @shawnt00 No, I did because after selecting it, I wasn't able to meet the constraints as per the data. I believe, having a single, double or triple flag in a row does not have any connection with writing the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this going to be horribly slow?

```
select t1.Code, t2.Code, t3.Code, t4.Code, t5.Code, t6.Code
from Table t1, Table t2, Table t3, Table t4, Table t5, Table t6
where   t1.Code < t2.Code and t2.Code < t3.Code
    and t3.Code < t4.Code and t4.Code < t5.Code and t5.Code < t6.Code
    and t1.Designer  + t2.Designer  + t3.Designer  + t4.Designer  + t5.Designer  + t6.Designer  >= 4
    and t1.Exclusive + t2.Exclusive + t3.Exclusive + t4.Exclusive + t5.Exclusive + t6.Exclusive >= 4
    and t1.Handloom  + t2.Handloom  + t3.Handloom  + t4.Handloom  + t5.Handloom  + t6.Handloom  >= 4
order by t1.Code, t2.Code, t3.Code, t4.Code, t5.Code, t6.Code
limit 1;
```

It seems you want the alphabetically lowest combination of product codes that satisfy your condition. I don't know if the 6-way cross join is going to be a performance issue but I believe it's correct per the requirement and possibly a reasonable starting point.

Depending on how much you know about the data in advance you might improve performance by eliminating rows (and thus the total number of row combinations) where only a single flag is set.

I tried this on SQL Server. Without the limit of one row it returns 157 matches. AFIJNP is number 69. There are 7 that include B, the first of which is ABDIJO. If I change the query to sort first on t6.Code then the result is ADEFIJ. So I don't know if I understand that part of your requirement.

Comment: It is giving output as A, C, I, N, O, P, which is meeting the criteria and is very close to the answer. But, somehow it is not giving the smallest alphabetical sum or the row_number sum. Only a slight difference.

Comment: Yes, I think it is the answer. It helps. Really appreciate your help. But why sort on t6.Code first?

Comment: I sorted on the sum of ascii(Code) (in SQL Server) and get ADEFIJ.

Comment: In the real data, I will be selecting 32 out of 320 rows based on 10 to 12 constraints, so do u think 32 self joins will do any harm to the performance?

Comment: Might be doable if you only want a single row. Perhaps you can add some extra constraints to help it abandon the search early or break it into smaller pieces. Obviously indexing would be important. In general terms a 32-way join is likely to never finish (320^32 is a _really_ big number.)

Comment: I feel 32-way join would be too big for the system to handle and if I use it is production, I don't know the consequences. Is there an alternate to this?

Comment: I think you'll need to add more details about the problem. Or perhaps you can search for "SQL" and "linear programming" and get some alternate approaches that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Yes now i m planning to work out on this through binary linear programming

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT Product_ID, Designer, Exclusive, Handloom
    FROM table-name
    WHERE Designer <> 0
    AND (Exclusive <> 0 OR Handloom <> 0)
    LIMIT 6 ;
```

Comment: This won't work if the table has 300 items and all but the last 4 records have a 0 for `Handloom` (for instance).

Comment: I agree with JNevil. Thanks for the efforts. I am in need of a generic solution (as JNevil mentioned). I tried using sum clause, but couldn't do.

Comment: Very good question @Amit, I gave +1, `(A, F, I, J, N, P)`, >=4 are Exclusive `(I, J, N, P)`, and >=4 are Handloom `(A, F, I, J)` . So here at-least the common elements in the three sets which occurred twice is picked. And so we get `a,f,i,j,n,p`

Comment: @JNevil...can you describe why your example doesn't work with the query?  I don't understand.  thx

Comment: If the table has the first two columns = 1 and the last column = 0 (1,1,0) for 30 records, then the 4 last records are 0,0,1. This statement will pull A,B,C,D,E,F which doesn't satisfy the third condition in the question where Handloom must also be >=4.

Comment: Wouldn't the 0,0,1 be disqualified because the where contains Designer <> 0 AND (Exclusive <> 0 or Handloom <> 0)?  Am I just being a veg?

Comment: Yep, being a veg.  I get it now :)

Comment: @MikeTWebb It will not reach till 0,0,1 as it so down in the table. The query will select A,B,C,D,E,F that do not satisfy the constraints in the problem. Handloom will be 0 as per your query.

Comment: That is the reason the record  `o` is not selected even though  `O           0           1           1`. As the priority is on `Designer` column

Comment: If you have a 30 record table where the first 24 records are `1,1,0` and the last 6 records are `1,1,1`. The right answer would be rows `25,26,27,28,29,30` but this will give you `1,2,3,4,5,6`

Comment: @JNevill Just a small correction to your comment. Since we will start from the top, right answer in that case should be 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28.

Comment: Oh yes... good point. The count(records)=6 and the >=4 across each field... I keep getting backwards.

Comment: @Amit. Please help me understand this. why for `Exclusive(I, J, N, P)` why not `O`is included ? Aren't you giving priority to Designer . I mean where `Exclusive = 1 AND Designer = 1` ?

Comment: @MySQLRockstar Oops, I gues instead of P, it should be O in the final output as the sum of letters will be lower in that case. Since I did it manually, I missed it. Thanks for correction.

Comment: This answer was based on what was stated in the beginning as final output `a,f,i,j,n,p`. Now that you have changed it to  `a,f,i,j,n,o`. Then I have to change my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand the question... Is there more to this table than what we're seeing? Here's what I think you want:

```
select      Product_ID,
            SUM(Designer) as Designer_cnt,
            SUM(Exclusive) as Exclusive_cnt,
            SUM(Handloom) as Handloom_cnt
from        myTable
group by    Product_ID
having      Designer_cnt >= 4
    or      Exclusive_cnt >= 4
    or      Handloom_cnt >= 4
```

If you want all 3 columns to have a total of 4, change the `or` in the `having` clause to `and`.

Comment: This did not give any row as output. There are actually a lot of rows and this table is a small representation of the actual data. In this, total product_IDs needed <= 6, Designer items needed>=4, Exclusive items>=4, Handloom items>=4

Comment: After reading your notes on another comment I realized this isn't quite what you're looking for. Sorry.