# How to proceed with my Spark / Scala project

Tags: sql, eclipse, scala, hive, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and Scala. I am working on a Scala project where I will have data access from SQL Server.

There is a table in SQL Server has info about clothes. itemCode is the primary key and several attributes with Boolean value 0/1 - Designer, Exclusive, Handloom and several other columns having attributes of the product etc.

```
Code Designer Exclusive Handloom
A        1       0         1
B        1       0         0
C        0       0         1
D        0       1         0
E        0       1         0
F        1       0         1
G        0       1         0
H        0       0         0
I        1       1         1
J        1       1         1
K        0       0         1
L        0       1         0
M        0       1         0
N        1       1         0
O        0       1         1
P        1       1         0
```

and the list continues.

I have to select a collection of 32 items out of 320 items that have ATLEAST:
8 Designer, 8 Exclusive, 8 Handloom, 8 WeddingStyle, 8 PartyStyle,
8 Silk, 8 Georgette

I had solved the problem in MS Excel solver (it uses Gradient Descent algo) by adding an extra column and using sumproduct function between added column and required columns. So, the problem was solved there and it took around 1 minute 30 seconds for the same.

Also, the problem can be solved by writing an SQL query with 32 joins (so many), for example, if i want to select 6 items out of those 16 above with atleast 4 items designer, 4 exclusive, 4 handloom, the query would be like in my post: [MYSQL - Select rows fulfilling many count conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567925/mysql-select-rows-fulfilling-many-count-conditions/29568693#29568693)

In production, I have to fetch 32 rows like this way, So my question is how do I proceed further with the project.

I am working on Scala IDE for Eclipse, and have added spark mllib there. I have fetched data via JDBC and stored in a dataframe, and the created a temporary table:
    dataFrame.registerTempTable("Data")

There is a class optimizer in mllib optimization that uses gradient descent (like excel solver does) to solve problems. But, that is for machine learning and takes as input training data.

I am not able to understand how do I proceed with my project. Can i use mllib, or use a better simple version of the sql with sparkSQL. I need serious help.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track! Keep it up!

Comment: But what do I do next? Mllib is for machine learning, but I am not creating a model, so can I use class optimizer for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-dataframes rather than MLLib.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem through linear programming. I have now used lpsolver library for java in my scala project. It is giving almost the same result as in excel solver.